# IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.1

I know this question has been answered, but I don't understand what people exactly do (about certificates, ssl) and they all use a localhost but not me.

I used this sample as my example [OpenIdConnect](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore)

I'm using:

- A web app
- A web API

Both are using .Net Core 2.1. The Web App is using the Azure AD connection to get a JwtBearer token, that is sent to the API.

Seeing the route `/api/information` in the API, a request is sent from the Web App to the API, and the API is returning the error above.

The error is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://.onmicrosoft.com/<big Guid of 72 chars>/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

So I tried to solve this error, by adding certificates, adding the neccessary libraries (`System.Net.Http` v4.3.3), checked every permission in Azure AD but none of these worked.

If you need more information, I can provide them by adding them in this post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved it by replacing, in `appsettings.json` :

```
"AzureAd": {
     "Instance": "<APP_Uri_from_Azure_Portal>",
...
}
```

To

```
"AzureAd": {
     "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
...
}
```

Comment: As an explanation here, reason for the error is that it is trying to download the OpenId configuration document from `{instance}{tenantid}/.well-known/openid-configuration`, so like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration`. This document contains the URL where token signing public keys can be acquired from, among other things. The authentication handler loads this at startup to load up its config for validating tokens provided by the identity provider. So with Azure AD, you must use the Azure AD instance's URL + your tenant id (or "common" for multi-tenant).

Comment: But since you provided another URL/URI, it of course was unable to find the metadata document and crashed.

Answer (score 16):

If anyone has this issue and is using the Azure B2C the instance is your root url for your azure b2c tenant. e.g. https://myroot.b2clogin.com/. The domain should be: myroot.onmicrosoft.com/

Make sure there is no https in the domain.

This worked for me.

```
{
    "AzureADB2C": {
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
        "ClientId": "<app-registration-app-client-id>",
        "ClientSecret": "<secret-value>",
        "Domain": "<domain-name>.onmicrosoft.com/",
        "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_profile",
        "Instance": "https://<domain-name>.b2clogin.com/",
        "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_reset",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signupsignin"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! In my case, I had to adjust the Instance and Domain to the format described

Comment: Also occurs if you use the wrong policy IDs

Answer (score 12):

Resolved the issue by adding below code in *Startup-->Configure*

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls 
                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Comment: Thanks this finally worked for me.  FYI, I developed some code that worked in .net core 3.1 to validate the signatures but I then put that code in a .net 4.x project and the code would not work and gave the same error as the OP got.  I guess these settings are not set by default in .net 4.x but are set by default in .net core 3.1

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in one of the comments above by @juunas The authentication handler loads this configuration file at startup to load up its config for validating tokens provided by the identity provider.

The file path end point can also be found in app registration section. If you go to app registration => Overview => Endpoints then look for OpenID Connect configuration endpoint (v2)

[image]

Startup.cs code for B2C authentication handler looks like below and I have supplied the values in appsettings

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
          .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
          {
              jwtOptions.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
              jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
              jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
              {
                  OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
              };
          });

 "AzureAdB2C": {
         "Tenant": "xxxxxxxxxb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
         "Instance": "xxxxxxxxxxxb2c.b2clogin.com",
         "ClientId": "xxxxxx-764c-4e4a-b0ec-xxxxxxf",
         "Policy": "B2C_1_signin1",
         "ScopeRead": "demo.read",

               },
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was firewall/network related - I could access the /.well-known/openid-configuration URL when I typed it in a browser, but the API itself couldn't (the API and Identity Server are being hosted in the same app).  The API was being hosted in Azure and I had created an Outbound Security Rule (for the Network Security Group that was associated with the subnet which was integrated to my app service plan that the API belonged to) which prevented the API from calling any other app services in its app service plan, including itself.  Adding a new Outbound Security Rule to allow that fixed my issue (I realise this resulted in a very similar error to the submitter but for a different reason and is more of an edge case - most probably don't have such restrictions setup).

Comment: This really helped me! In our case it was similar, but a little different. The box "Outbound internet traffic" was checked under "Application routing" which was forcing any external network traffic through the virtual network. Once I unchecked that box, it all started working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

On my case, the Authority key was missing from my appSettings.

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>",
    "ClientId": "...",
    "TenantId": "...",
    "Domain": "https://<your name>.b2clogin.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_susi",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_reset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit_profile",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer from @AmirAli.

My error looked like this after using the tool `msidentity-app-sync tool` with .NET 6:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/tools/app-provisioning-tool/vs2019-16.9-how-to-use.md

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain
> configuration from:
> 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<myAD>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'

Changed `AzureAd:Instance` in `appsettings.json` from default `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` to `https://<myAD>.b2clogin.com/` and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, https://.b2clogin.com was blocked by the firewall, and the error message was exactly the same, so allowing the URL (by modifying firewall rules) allowing the server to access https://xxxx.b2clogin.com solved the issue. I hope it helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had run the app from a couple of places (VSCode, Rider and console) and some process was still running in the background. Just restarted the PC and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case today, I had to restart the app service and then it was working again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure B2C, aAdd the Tenant name properly with the ".b2clogin.com"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case . I had to add "Authority" to appsettings.json . When adding Authority include till . Azure was adding "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" at the end by default. Make sure overall url matches that is shown as in endpoints. [When](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc2KT.png)

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://XXX.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "13aead9c-e120-43eb-9b8f-c1eb5d1d2297",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Scopes": "apidata.read apidata.write",
    "TenantId": "63588920-1bdd-42ee-93e6-6f0f1cc67d8f",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_ProfileEdit",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordReset",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
    "Authority": "https://xxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpSignIn/"
  }
```