# "InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'"

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I've deployed my API and Client app on Docker, but for the life of me, the web app cannot call the API, I keep getting an exception.

I added the following line suggested in other posts, but it did not work.

```
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
```

Exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'.
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
at IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Most likely your authority is configured incorrectly or it is unable to connect to the metadata endpoint.

Comment: Where did you add the line ShowPII=true?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, I'm setting it in  'ConfigureServices'

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, the issue is that my web ui app cannot call the API since the API is throwing that error [PII is hidden], so i added ShowPII=true , but still the error persists

Comment: @JaneSenya In which project? It should be in the IdentityServer startup. But showing the error is not going to solve the problem. It can  only help you to find out what the problem is.

Comment: Oh, I'm setting it at the API project, let me try adding it to the IDS project and revert back to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742248/idx20803-unable-to-obtain-configuration-from)

Comment: @RuardvanElburg after adding 'ShowPII' in IDS project it worked, I could see the actual error in the logs, apparently the API couldn't access the configuration document. I was able to fix the issue from there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am facing same issue in .net core 2.1 & When I am tryin to enable ShowPII it says : IdentityModelEventSource does not have a ShowPII property. Please guide how to enable it in .net core 2.1

Comment: For my case, I had wrong Authority endpoint to the resource API. Thanks @juunas !

Comment: I got the same error. The key is that if you call 
app.MapControllers();
then call
app.UseSwagger(); 
You will get this strange error which is not related to PII.

So, the solution is switch the order. Good luck

Answer (score 111):

We need to enable viewing of PII logs so we can see more details about the error:
Add the following line in ConfigureServices() to Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; //Add this line
    ....
```

Comment: Same is mentioned in https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/PII

Comment: This line should be added in the Resource.API project (Not in the IDP project), don't do the same mistake as I did :)

Comment: `using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;`  will provide the `IdentityModelEventSource`.

Comment: I am facing same issue in .net core 2.1 & When I am tryin to enable ShowPII it says : IdentityModelEventSource does not have a ShowPII property. Please guide how to enable it in .net core 2.1

Comment: It is not the root cause for me. When I add your line. A new error will throw that 
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: XXX

Answer (score 37):

In my case, this happened while I was developing an identity prototype with the Identity Server 4 on the localhost environment, and my authority was configured incorrectly.

I was following an example from Identity Server 4, the issue was that the Quickstart example of Identity Server 4 contained 3 projects:

- Identity Server. with endpoint => `https://localhost:5001`
- Api (called Resource Api or Consumer Api).
- Client.

In the example that was provided, the Identity Server was set to https with endpoint `https://localhost:5001`.
But the Authority in Consumer Api was set to `http://localhost:5000`.

So when the client tries to connect to Consumer Api, it gets the `http://localhost:5000` address and tries to look at `http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration` and this does not exist. It exists only on `https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

So far so good.

The solution is to ensure you are using the same endpoint of the identity server on your consumer authority:

```
options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this still is true, you spared me a lot of head aches.

Comment: Even after 4 decades of coding, still can't see the wood for the trees sometimes :) Thanks

Answer (score 30):

If anyone is experiencing this during development, I was able to solve this by clearing my developer certs then recreating them.

```sh
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Comment: This " dotnet dev-certs https --trust " Does not work on a Linux machine, or on Azure VM

Comment: @HarounHajem I actually run Linux and it works fine on my machine.  You might have to install the tool. https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-dev-certs

Comment: wow this is the answer that works for me! thanks heaps

Comment: This did the trick for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: For me as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Enabling TLS 1.2 solved the issue

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Comment: Where did you add this?

Comment: @alcaprar first line in `ConfigureServices`

Comment: So glad I saw this! Thanks!!

Answer (score 16):

In .NET 6 add code after `builder` in `Program.cs`. Example:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
```

For me the error was:

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain
> configuration from:
> 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<myAD>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'

Solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70925127/3850405

Answer (score 9):

If this it's related to a Visual Studio Web Application project using the "Connect to an existing store in the cloud" AKA "Azure Active Directory B2C" the proposed config it's not good.

Its also needed to change the used userflow in Azure like mentioned in the following article: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Azure-AD-B2C-issuer-claim-support

Change

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp",
  "ClientId": "{clientId}",
  "Domain": "{tenant}.b2clogin.com",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "{policy}"
}
```

To

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "{clientId}",
    "Domain": "{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "{policy}"
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to drop /tfp also?

Comment: I was missing TenantId it turned out.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this issue after 60 mins.

You may installed both

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
```

and

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
```

Then, you will get this extremely strange issue.

So, the anwser is remove the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`.

Comment: wtf it works : D Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

This error can also happen when the identity server is not running.

Comment: In my case. Both client and identity server was running, but the client always finishes first. Client is slightly ahead but is still enough for the client to unable to detect the identity server.

Answer (score 4):

In **.Net 6** using **Blazor Server**, I had to add the ShowPII statement right before app.Run() in program.cs. If I added it up at top of Main, it would not have any effect. I'm sure you could narrow down a more precise location if you cared to, but this worked for me.

```
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
app.Run();
```

My issue was a 404 error.

Using OIDC with endpoint hosted on B2C, I would offer this prescriptive advice - identify your custom policy in the B2C portal under Identity Experience Framework, click on it, copy the url for the OpenID Connect discovery endpoint, and add that as your options.MetadataAddress value. You'll need the 'p' querystring value in the url which is just your policy name.

Comment: adding directly before `app.Run()` (instead of much earlier in `Program.cs`) also helps on "normal" ASP.Net Core, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The solution its quite tricky, I know this is an old issue but I had the exact same issue last week and I spend quite a lot of time solving it.
This issue is because the Client app is not trusting the Kestrel certificate of the API app.

On the Dockerfile of the client application, you should add something like this in order to add the certificate used on the API application to the trusted CA of the client.

```
COPY ["API-KESTREL-CERTIFICATE.crt", "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/"]
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

BIG NOTE HERE! (At least on a local environment) you should care about the domain of the API certificate. In my case (Local environment) I had to create a multiple domains certificate because the "localhost" of the API is not the same "localhost" of the client app because they are running on different docker containers. 
Being said that, for the Kestrel certificate of the API I followed this guide to create multiple-domains self-signed certificates https://www.rpkamp.com/2014/08/25/setting-up-a-multi-domain-self-signed-ssl-certificate/ and on the .cnf file in the DNS section, I did something like this and did the trick.

```
DNS.1 = localhost
DNS.2 = host.docker.internal
```

Finally, in the authority of the client application be sure of being addressing the proper domain and should be working.

I hope it helps!

Comment: can you share what's the authority URL you used?

Comment: Well, we had an IdentityServer project so it was basically the URL of that project...
The URL was depending on if it was deployed or It was just localhost:<port>

Comment: How can I find my Kestrel certificate when I am not using docker?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a B2C instance and related application entry pre-created, then created a new web app and let VS take me through the new web app Microsoft Identity Platform authentication type wizard (which actually worked nicely).  The default appsettings.json had this:

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://xxxxxx.b2clogin.com/",
"Domain": "xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
"TenantId": "xxxxx",
"ClientId": "xxxxx",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_signin",
"SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
"ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_reset",
"EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit_profile",
"EnablePiiLogging": true},
```

All that was required to fix it was remove the EnablePiiLogging line.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I enabled IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII and got to know that the well-known url was incorrect.
This is really helpful answer by @Mentor

Answer (score 1):

if you are using self-signed cert and imported into Trusted Root, it may be automatically deleted by Microsoft CAPI2 and thus JWT validation failed.
Either reimport your cert or add this entry in registry:
Key:   HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\AuthRoot
Name:  DisableRootAutoUpdate
Value: 1
Type:  REG_DWORD

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using Azure AD Authentication and my internet was not connected, after connecting internet it started working again. PEACE

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but in my case I want to handle this expection so that it shows a readable message to the user if they are facing authentication issues.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux I tried all the proposed options and none worked, what I had to do is:

1. generate a free [lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate for the development domain,
2. generate the pfx file and password using the lets encrypt files: `openssl pkcs12 -export -out ca-bundle.pfx -inkey private-key.key -in ca-bundle.crt`
3. setup Kestrel to use those certificates and password. like this examples: [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
4. done

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and it turns out I forgot to add  `app.UseIdentityServer();` to `StartUp.cs`. Adding this method to `Cofigure()` solved the issue for me.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
       //other config
        app.UseIdentityServer();
    }
```

Comment: that doesn't exist (anymore?)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following configuration in your `appsettings.json` file:

```json
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"
```

Reference (Github): https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2337#issuecomment-458772667

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error as a result of my hosts file being corrupted (Docker Desktop added a section but corrupted the original contents of the file). This meant that my instance of Identity Server was effectively not running.

Answer (score 0):

In our case we had a mismatch on one of the microservices configuration in our development environment for the AzureAdB2C's SignUpSignInPolicyId policy property.

All microservices where using this config

```json
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://ourawesometenant.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "aa2cb23f-d25c-4c34-a7cc-847a2bf36377",
    "Domain": "ourawesometenant.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_Default",
    "AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL": true
  }
```

the one that failed with the above error had this configuration with a different SignUpSignInPolicyId value to the other microservices.

```json
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://ourawesometenant.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "aa2cb23f-d25c-4c34-a7cc-847a2bf36377",
    "Domain": "ourawesometenant.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUp",
    "AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL": true
  }
```

making sure all microservices had the same AzureAdB2C configuration removed this error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following two lines in your `CounfigurationAuth` method:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
```

For me its working

Answer (score 0):

We had this error on Azure App Service. We needed to ensure that traffic to the endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/ is allowed through our Azure Firewall.
Our App Service is configured to have all outbound traffic routed over VNet through Azure Firewall using a route table.