# "InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'" With Azure Application Services .NET 4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Ran into an issue where I was getting the following error message.

[image]

Looking at this post -> ["InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435551/invalidoperationexception-idx20803-unable-to-obtain-configuration-from-pii)

I was able to correct this issue with - `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

Not sure if this was an update on Azure or the Identity provider on Azure, but I am just trying to look into this to see if I can find a root cause.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Azure identity provider. Please refer below document from microsoft for more details on TLS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Hope this helps :)