# ASP.NET Core Web API fails to validate auth token when published to Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, okta

I have an Angular app that uses Okta to manage user logins and connects to an ASP.NET Core Web API. The Angular app sends the Okta auth token along with all API requests. The API is meant to validate the auth token before processing the request and extract the uid.

I followed the directions on the Okta Dev website here:
https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/validate-access-tokens/dotnet/main/#validate-a-token

On my dev machine, everything works perfectly. However, once the API is deployed to Azure, this line in the `ValidateToken` method fails every time:

```
var discoveryDocument = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(ct);
```

The authorization server passed into the `confiurationManager` and the Azure server both share the same domain, so I don't think there would be a firewall or proxy issue. Has anyone else had similar issues with the `GetConfigurationAsync` method, and if so, how did you solve it?

Comment: What's the error message you received?

Comment: I'm getting InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: [my_auth_server_metadata_uri].

Comment: This looks like is related with the network connection between the my_auth_server_metadata_uri and Azure web app. How about directly inside the kudu with ping command.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a gov't Azure server, so ping is not allowed from the Kudu CMD console. However, rather, than ping, I was able to run nameresolver.exe on the domain I'm trying to hit, and it successfully returned the IP address, as well as aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58784678/1943644

Enabling TLS 1.2 solved the issue

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Putting that in the `ConfigureServices` section of `Startup.cs` solved the problem.