# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR generated using X509 certificate with Kestrel hosting in .NET 8 on Linux

Tags: linux, ssl, .net-6.0, .net-8.0, kestrel-http-server

I am currently working through upgrading a C#/.NET app from .NET 6.0 to .NET 8.0 on a Linux virtual machine (I'm working on a PC), and I am having some issues with getting HTTPS endpoints to work. I stumbled across [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/7.0/https-binding-kestrel) while looking for solutions, but I'm not 100% sure that is actually the issue, and if it is I'm not sure how to fix it :). I am retrieving a `X509Certificate2` crt/key pair from the local file system and using that to create a `IHostBuilder` object that uses HTTPS. Below is the current code I'm working with:

```
var certContents = File.ReadAllText(<local filepath>);
var certKeyContents = File.ReadAllText(<local key filepath>);
var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(certContents, certKeyContents);

return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.AddServerHeader = false;
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port, ops =>
                {
                    ops.UseHttps(cert);
                }); 
            }
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging => 
    {
    })
    .UseNLog();
```

The result of this is generally an error page that just shows "This site can’t provide a secure connection". I have primarily been using Google Chrome v122.0 and Postman v9.31 to test these calls. I have set breakpoints in code and it seems like I'm not even able to get to the backend with these errors since those breakpoints are never hit. Interestingly, I did find that I can get a little bit farther when I use FireFox (as in, it seems to be able to get access to the backend); it does not throw SSL errors, but will instead attempt to access our app's Keycloak instance (not locally hosted) to verify our SSO token and throws a IDX20803 error. Below is further exception code from that:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '<Keycloak URL>'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I have also noticed some IDX20803 errors that more follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435551/invalidoperationexception-idx20803-unable-to-obtain-configuration-from-pii?noredirect=1&lq=1) pattern.
This code works just fine in .NET 6, but I must be missing something in the updated .NET versions - any guidance is appreciated!

**What I've already tried**

- In the `options.Listen()` callback, attempted to add the below code block.

  - Result: no change in error

```
opt.AllowAnyClientCertificate();
opt.ClientCertificateValidation = (certif, chain, policyErrors) => true;
opt.ClientCertificateMode = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
opt.ServerCertificate = cert;
opt.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
    | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3
    | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls
    | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.None
    | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11
    | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls13
    | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default;
```

- In the `options.Listen()` callback, tried removing the `ops.UseHttps(cert)` call

  - Result: was able to make API calls to an HTTP URL, but HTTPS remained unavailable
- In the beginning of my Program.cs and Startup.cs files, attempted adding this line: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;`

  - Result: no change in error
- In the Configure method of the Startup.cs file, add `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`

  - Result: no change in error