# Call .NET CORE Web API Secure End-point from Angular by passing Azure B2C JWT Bearer token

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, angular9, asp.net-core-3.1, angular2-jwt

I need to call secure Web API from Angular 9 application by presenting the Azure B2C JWT Bearer token. I am using Angular 9 with .NET CORE 3.1 Web API. I have managed to generate Azure B2C token but stuck to call secure Web API end-point as I am getting 401 unauthorized error. I am passing token in the header from angular.

### Angular component calling Web API end-point

```
testAPI1(){
    console.log("calling test API ...");

    const myheaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': this.authService.accessToken
    });

    this.http.get('https://localhost:5001/txn/v1/Dashboard/GetMessage', {headers: myheaders})
        .subscribe((data)=>{
            console.warn(data);
        })
}
```

### Auth Service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements OnInit{

constructor(
    private oauthService: OAuthService,
    private router: Router

){// other code}


public get accessToken() { 
    return this.oauthService.getAccessToken(); 
}
```

### Web API controller & endpoint

```
[Authorize]
[Route("txn/v1/[controller]/[action]")]
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
[ApiController]
public class DashboardController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<HelloMessage> GetMessage()
    {
        var result = new HelloMessage()
        {
            GivenName = "james",
            ReturnMessage = "Dashboard@ Hello, Welcome to Digital tech"
        };
        return result;
    }
```

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       //JWT Authentication 
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(jwtConfig => 
            {
                jwtConfig.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ResourceId"];
                jwtConfig.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TanantId"]}";
                jwtConfig.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                jwtConfig.SaveToken = true;
                jwtConfig.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer =true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true

                };
        });

 //CORS policy
 services.AddCors(options =>
                          options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()));
```

### error

[image]

### request header in response

[image]

### visual studio event exception

[image]

### PII is Hidden error

[image]

Comment: I believe the issue is in HttpClient request header! but not sure 100%

Comment: Usually this is because your token is wrong or mismatched, so check the access token you pass in to make sure it is correct.

Comment: Could you please provide the screenshot of your request headers and which sdk you use to configure auth?

Comment: Hi Jim, I have put a screenshot of request header in above question, please refer to it

Comment: Hi. When we call the api projected by Azure AD b2C, we should set `Authorization` header as `Bearer {accessToken}`

Comment: I have added Bearer token and not getting 401 error but there is still something missing... I got an exception on .NET CORE Web API side... I paste the error in question ... many thanks for support me on this

Comment: Maybe this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744127/1595293

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the code you provided, you use the wrong `Authority`. If we use Azure AD B2C, the  `Authority` should be like`https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{your-tenant-domain}/{your-policy-name}/v2.0`.

For example

**Web API Application**

a. `appsettings.json`.

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://<your tenant name>.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": " your client id",
    "Domain": "your tenant domain",
"TenantId": "your tenant id",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "your policy name"
  },
  ...
}
```

b. `Startup.cs`.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(jwtConfig =>
            {
                jwtConfig.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
                jwtConfig.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Domain"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:SignUpSignInPolicyId"]}/v2.0";
                jwtConfig.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                jwtConfig.SaveToken = true;
                jwtConfig.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidAudience= jwtConfig.Audience,
                    ValidIssuer = $"{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TenantId"]}/v2.0/"
                };

            });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod());
            });
            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

**Angular component calling Web API end-point**

```
public getMessage() {
    const myheaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+this.oauthService.getAccessToken(),
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  });
   console.log(myheaders)
    this.http.get("https://localhost:44389/weatherforecast", {headers: myheaders})
      .subscribe(r => {
        this.message = JSON.stringify(r) 
        console.log("message: ", this.message);
      });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jim ... many thanks I was so stuck with this... I have managed to get token ... another small relevant issue but working on it